# Executing a procedure with conversion error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void MinMax(int tab[],int* min, int& max)
{
    int size=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4095; i++)
    {
        if(tab[i]==-1) break;
        size++;
    }
    size=(int)size;
    for(int passes=0; passes<size; passes++)
    {
        if(tab[passes]<tab[passes+1])
        {
            swap(tab[passes],tab[passes+1]);
        };
    }
    min=tab[size];
    cout<<min<<" ";
    for(int passes=0; passes<size; passes++)
    {
        if(tab[passes]>tab[passes+1])
        {
            swap(tab[passes],tab[passes+1]);
        };
    }
    max=tab[size];
    cout<<max<<" ";

}
int main()
{
    int z1[]= {10,2,5,7,4,-1};
    int min, max;
    MinMax(z1,min,max);
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        cout<<z1[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

I need to write some values in z1 in main function, then execute MinMax. It should find smallest and biggest value from an array. The first problem is when i try to compile it, there is en error about converting int to int* and i can't assign tab[size] to min. I should also use 2 intigers when executing MinMax, but it doesn't work.

Comment: And `size=(int)size;` serves no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MinMax(int tab[],int* min, int& max)
//                       ^
```

This appears to be a typo.

Given the way you're passing the argument, and given the way you're using it inside `MinMax`, I suspect you meant `int&`, like you have for `max`.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you assign an integer to a pointer variable by doing `min=tab[size];` where min is `int *` type and tab[size] is `int`

In order to correct this behavior, you should assign tab[size] to the value min is pointing to with the deference operator: `*min = tab[size]`

This should correct your error.

Comment: I did it, the code now looks like this
`void MinMax(int tab[],int* min, int& max)


 cout<<tab[size-1];

 *min=tab[size-1];
 cout<<min;

 
 cout<<tab[size];
 
 max=tab[size];
 cout<<max;
}`
But I receive 2 as an output, then the program crashes. I need *min and &max to appear, why is this still wrong?

Comment: Sorry for asking such stupid question, changed `*min=tab[size-1];` to `min=&tab[size-1];` and everything works fine.